# prevent expression under \min from affecting vertical space below line

Tags: align, vertical-spacing

In a two-line `align` environment, I am trying to put a math expression under a `\min` on the top line without it affecting the vertical spacing between the top and bottom lines. I started with

```
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \min~~ & g(x) \\
                  & \hspace{1em} + h(x) \\
    \text{s.t.}~~ & x \in X
\end{align*}
```

but now I am trying to get something like

```
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \min_{x \in X} ~~ & g(x) \\
                             & \hspace{1em} + h(x)
\end{align*}
```

and the problem is that the vertical space between `g(x)` and `h(x)` is larger now than it was before. Picture:

[image]

I have looked into wrapping the expression in a `\smash{}`. It seems not to suit me though because it affects the spacing between `\min` and the expression. How can I get something like the bottom that retains the original spacing between `g(x)` and `h(x)`?

Comment: `\mathop{\smash{\min_{x\in X}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, that is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\mathop{\smash{\min_{x\in X}}}`